# Remove DF Rows Based on a CSV File (Pandas,Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Right now, I am trying to create a function that removes rows based on certain criteria that are outlined within an excel file.  This excel file (bad words2) contains word pairs that should be removed from within the DF and looks like this:

```
header
the man
is a
```

The second part of my code is function I am trying to apply

```
import pandas as pd
data = ({'words':['the man','is a','good guy']})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

xl = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/j/Desktop/bad words2.xlsx')
badwords = xl.parse()
badwords = badwords['header']

def removewords(x):
    for w in x:
        pattern = '^'+''.join('(?=.*{})'.format(word) for word in w.split())
        df[df['words'].str.contains(pattern)==False]
        df.dropna()


 print(removewords(badwords))
```

So ideally, at the end of applying this function, I should end up with a DF that contains only:

```
 words
 good guy
```

However, right now, all that this function returns is 'None'.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry are you just wanting to filter out words that are in the pattern or filter out words that are not in the pattern? anyway unclear what you are trying to do but this line does nothing without an assignment: `df[df['words'].str.contains(pattern)==False]` should be `df = df[df['words'].str.contains(pattern)==False]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1. The final two operations return a new DataFrame. I.e. they do not modify the DataFrame in-place. You need to assign the result of those operations to something, e.g. `df`.
2. And then if you do the above, the variable `df` is not available for assignment within the scope of the function. You can pass it in as an argument. (Please note: This is not a problem with your code, but with the proposed solution.) Alternatively you could instantiate a new DataFrame within the function.
3. You are not returning the DataFrame at the end of your function.

Try instead:

```
def removewords(df,x):
    for w in x:
        pattern = '^'+''.join('(?=.*{})'.format(word) for word in w.split())
        df = df[df['words'].str.contains(pattern)==False]
        df = df.dropna()
    return df

print(removewords(df,badwords))
```

Comment: Hi Bernie thanks for the input.  However, when I try to assign any type of variable to df (i.e. df = ), I get the error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment

Comment: So problem solved, second problem springs up -- the changes being made don't "stack" within the for loop.  So using the code above, the return output is "is a / good guy".  I was hoping to remove all word pairs that appeared in my excel file so that my final return output was JUST 'Good Guy'

Comment: I made a mistake in the indentation of the `return` statement. Please see edited code which now does what you want.